# Setting first page on EPiServer CMS 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, episerver-6

For some reason, I can't work out how to set the 'home page' of an EPiServer project I'm working on. The default.aspx in my project is obviously used as a template for a pagetype I've defined using page type builder so it doesn't act as the start page as such. How do I (developer) or/and editor or admin set it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open episerver.config, find the "sitesettings" node and set "pageStartId" to the pageID of your choice.

Comment: How would I get the ID of the page I wanted to the site to start at though? Also - it's obviously not possible for a client to access this config file at editor level - so what if they create a page that they would like as the start page?

Comment: If you install the template site, the startpage always has PageID=3. You can always find the PageID of any given page by going to edit mode and hovering your mouse over a page. The only way to set the startpage is at file level (unless you write a custom admin plugin). Keep in mind that licensing issues may arise if you create more than one startpage/site in your EPiServer installation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Arild, really appreciate the explanation.